# Jquery addeventListener. object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this small script that has been in use for 6 months. Now suddenly without any updates to Windows it suddenly does not work in IE8. IE8 just gives me "object doesn't support this property or method" for the lines containing addEventListener. It works properly in anything above IE8.

The script should update one field based on two conditions. Both conditions fires on the addEventListener.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var skyddarb = document.getElementById("skyddsarbetsorder");
  var pfield = $('#priofield')[0];
  message_index = pfield.options[pfield.selectedIndex].text;
  var changePrioField = (function(e){
    if (skyddarb.checked) {
            $("#jobcodekey").val('200-1');
        } else if (message_index.toLowerCase().indexOf('1') >= 0){
            $("#jobcodekey").val('121-0');
        } else if (message_index.toLowerCase().indexOf('2') >= 0){
            $("#jobcodekey").val('121-0');
        } else if (message_index.toLowerCase().indexOf('3') >= 0){
            $("#jobcodekey").val('122-0');
        }
    console.log("value: %s, text: %s", pfield.value, pfield.textContent);
  });
pfield.addEventListener("change", changePrioField);
skyddarb.addEventListener("change", changePrioField);
});
```

Comment: Why not use `.on` rather than `addeventListener`? Old cross-browser compatibility is one of the main selling points of jQuery, after all

Comment: @CertainPerformance I did try swapping out ".addEventListener" to ".on" directly. But then nothing fires. Will I have to modify the script more for that?

Comment: The problem and reason for using addEventListener from start was that I have two listeners. Not sure how to modify this using .on or onchange. Trying that earlier I was only able to get one of them to fire. @CertainPerformance

Comment: eg `$('#priofield').on('change', changePrioField);` and `$('#skyddsarbetsorder').on('change', changePrioField);`

Comment: Thank you very much @CertainPerformance.